# Trouble with the scope of variables in a class?

Tags: python, scope, pybrain

So I'm in the process of making a class in Python that creates a network (with pybrain) using solely the numeric input it's given {just a little process to get my feet wet in Pybrain's API}.

My problem is, I'm rather unfamiliar with how scopes work in classes, and while I basically have the program set up properly, it keeps returning a keyerror.

All the variables needed to be acted upon are created in the **init** function; the method I'm working on for the class is trying to call upon one of the variables, declared in the **init** function using the vars()[] method in Python. (you can actually see a portion of the code's...rough draft here:
[Matching Binary operators in Tuples to Dictionary Items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11590138/matching-binary-operators-in-tuples-to-dictionary-items)

Anyways, the method is:

```
    def constructnetwork(self):
    """constructs network using gathered data in __init__"""
       if self.recurrent:
            self.network = pybrain.RecurrentNetwork  
            #add modules/connections here
       elif self.forward:
            self.network = pybrain.FeedForwardNetwork
       else:
            self.network = pybrain.network

       print vars()[self.CONNECT+str(1)]
       print vars()[self.CONNECT+str(2)]
       print self.network
```

(pardon the bad spacing, it didn't copy and paste over well.) The part that's raising the KeyError is the "print vars()[self.CONNECT+str(1)], which should retreive the value of the variable "Connection1" (self.CONNECT = 'Connection'), but calls a keyerror.

How do I get the variables to transfer over? If you need more information to help just ask, I'm trying to keep the quesiton as short as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`vars()` returns a reference to the dictionary of *local* variables.  If you used `vars()` in your `__init__` (as the code in the post you linked to suggests), then you just created a local variable in that method, which isn't accessible from anywhere outside that method.

What is it that you think `vars()` does, and what are you trying to do?  I have a hunch that what you want is `getattr` and `setattr`, or just a dictionary, and not `vars`.

Edit: Based on your comment, it sounds like, indeed, you shouldn't use `vars`.  You would be better off, in `__init__`, doing something like:

```
 self.connections = {}
 self.connections[1] = "This is connection 1"
```

then in your method, do:

```
 self.connections[1]
```

This is just a vague guess based on your code, though.  I can't really tell what you are intending for this "connection".  Do you want it to be some data associated with your object?

Comment: I thought vars() defined a variable and could be adjusted....the point was to use vars plus some loops and var+=1 to create new variables according to the input, such that vars()[CONNECT+str(countingvariable)] would create Connectionx where x is the value of counting variable increased by one?

Comment: And then call these newly defined variables in a class that would construct the network based on the modules/connections I'd created/assigned in __init__

Comment: Am I just retarded? I spent ~3 hours setting up this __init__ function and it's huge...

Comment: could I do self.connections[variable] where variable changes regularly? Is it that simple?!

Comment: You can certainly do that, yes.  I can't quite tell what you're trying to accomplish, but using `vars` is almost certainly not the right choice.

Comment: Pybrain has modules (types of neurons) that are linked via connections, basically. Connection links x to y and may apply a transformation to the data in the process.....

Comment: You should try constructing a simple class that has nothing to do with pybrain, just to test your understanding of how class/instance attributes work.  If you have difficulty, you can post a question about that.  Your questions here and in the earlier post include a lot of details that are extraneous to what you're really having trouble with.